# logcat doesn't recognize --regex option

Tags: android, regex, android-logcat

According to documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html
logcat should support the option:

```
-e <expr>, --regex=<expr>   Only print lines where the log message matches <expr> where <expr> is a regular expression.
```

However I cannot run logcat with this option:

```
$ ./adb logcat --regex="Vocabulary"
unknown option -- -Unrecognized Option

$ ./adb logcat -e "Vocabulary"
unknown option -- eUnrecognized Option
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

It happen because your device not support it,

Please run this:

```
adb shell logcat --help
```

And please search something like this:

```
-e <expr>, --regex=<expr>
    Only print lines where the log message matches <expr>
    where <expr> is a regular expression
```

if not, **your device not support regular expressions**.

Possible solution:

```
adb logcat | grep -e 'xxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

adb logcat regex will not work on TAG's. So check word "Vocabulary" is a TAG.
and If you want search with TAG's use:

```
adb logcat -s TAG.
```